# In WndProc How to find the sender of the message

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I am creating a winform. In this I am creating a form inside another form. I am getting mouse clicks in WndProc message in child form. Is there anyway to find out the sender of the message. I want to know based on which window coordinate I am getting the mouse clicks.

EDIT:
    There are three things.Form1,form2,minbutton(customized taskbar button). Form2 is inside form1.minButton is inside form2. When I click minbutton, I want to know which is sending the mouseclicks.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)   
{
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            {
                MessageBox.Show("MT L Button Up");
                ReleaseCapture();
                SetCapture((int)parent.Handle);
                captured = false;
                Point pnt_Dummy = new Point((int)m.LParam);
                pnt_Dummy = parent.PointToClient(pnt_Dummy);
                MessageBox.Show("MinTray " + pnt_Dummy.X + "," + pnt_Dummy.Y);
                Debug.WriteLine(m.HWnd.ToString());
                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: are you sending the mouse clicks originally from one form to the other form?

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: Can you use WindowFromPoint once you get mouse coordinates

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: what if its user based, so hasnt originated from any of the items you mentioned?  what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As it says on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttonup) WM_LBUTTONUP recieves coordinates relative to the upper-left corner of the window client area. In your case coordinates are relative to the same window whose `WndProc` you have overriden.

Comment: And you don't need to call `parent.PointToClient(pnt_Dummy)`, that just makes no sence.